# Swift - Problema con UIDatePicker al añadir Target

Tags: swift

En mi aplicación necesito que se muestre la fecha escogida con un DatePicker en un Label. 
Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var pickerDat: UIDatePicker!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerDat.addTarget(self, action: Selector("diaHora:"), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    pickerDat.datePickerMode = .date
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  func diaHora(pickerDat: UIDatePicker){
    let formatoFechaHora = DateFormatter ()
    formatoFechaHora.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    let dat = formatoFechaHora.string(from: pickerDat.date)

    label.text = dat
  }
}
```

Al elegir la fecha en la aplicación salta el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error creo que se encuentra en el paso del parámetro action en el método de añadir el target, puede ser que la nueva versión de Swift no admita esa sintaxis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución, la nueva sintaxtis del `Selector()`es `#selector()`además de que no se pasa como parámetro un string con dos puntos como último caracter, sino directamente la función.
Por lo que el código pasa de:

```
pickerDat.addTarget(self, action: Selector("diaHora:"), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

a:

```
pickerDat.addTarget(self, action: #selector(diaHora), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```